# Tengo la columna incluida en un archivo xlsx pero al ejecutar me da un key error

Tags: google-colab

[image: Aca se puede ver que la columna fechas existe y cuando voy a combinarla con el otro dataframe me marca el error texto en negrita]
Aca se puede ver que la columna fechas existe y cuando voy a combinarla con el otro dataframe me marca el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, por favor agrega el código y el error en formato de texto. ;)

Comment: Y de paso, indica la versión de pandas que estás usando.